# how to give each div a different animation speed with css animation

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

Struggling to even get started figuring this out, I am working on a website for a friend, here is a one of the pages..

http://sarahboulton.co.uk/livingroom.html

So on refresh it brings up one of four constellations of letters, which shift their constellations using math random.

We were hoping to start applying small animations to the letters.. something along these lines..

```
.lipbalm {
animation: shake 0.1s; 
animation-iteration-count: infinite; }

@keyframes shake {
    0% { transform: translate(0px)  }
    50% { transform: translate(0.5px) }
    100% { transform: translate(0px) }
}
```

But whether these movements could be randomised for each letter, still small movements.. but using something similar to..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.goldrocks-g').css({'left' : (Math.random() * 250) + 350})
});
```

..each letter randomises its movement, maybe one ends up on..

```
@keyframes shake {
        0% { transform: translate(0px)  }
        50% { transform: translate(0.4px) }
        100% { transform: translate(0px) }
    }
```

.. and another has..

```
@keyframes shake {
        0% { transform: translate(0px)  }
        50% { transform: translate(0.1px) }
        100% { transform: translate(0px) }
    }
```

and something similar for the speed too? All the letters have their own div, might be easier to view the source of the page to see whats going on !

Comment: Java is a very different programming language; you're using JavaScript.

Comment: I'm confused are you trying to have the letter move forever, or just be  at random places each time you refresh the page ?

Answer (score 1):

The way I would approach this problem is by creating the a few variations of your shake class and then assign those classes at random when you are assigning the random constellation.

So something like this:

**css**

```
.shake-1{
  animation: shake-1 0.3s; 
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
.shake-2{
  animation: shake-2 0.3s; 
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
.shake-3{
  animation: shake-3 0.3s; 
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
@keyframes shake-1 {
  0% { transform: translate(0px) }
  50% { transform: translate(2px) }
  100% { transform: translate(0px) }
}
@keyframes shake-2 {
  0% { transform: translate(0px) }
  50% { transform: translate(-2px) }
  100% { transform: translate(0px) }
}
@keyframes shake-3 {
  0% { transform: translate(0px) }
  50% { transform: translate(0px, 2px) }
  100% { transform: translate(0px) }
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="dyinglight-d shake-1" style="left: 839.646px; top: 212.011px;">...</div>
<div class="dyinglight-y shake-2" style="left: 959.592px; top: 97.9469px;">...</div>

etc
```

Here's a codepen I made for you with your site's code to show an example of it working: https://codepen.io/ChrisRArendt/pen/jQXjNa

Answer (score 0):

You may generate CSS style using javaScript to integrate javaScript `Math.random()` into CSS logic.

For example you can generate 10 keyframes with names **shake1** to **shake10** with random transform on 50% and append this styles to the header style :

```
var css;
for (x=1;x=10;x++){
   css += '@keyframes shake'+  x.toString()  +' {';
   css += '0% { transform: translate(0px)}';
   css += '50% { transform: translate('+  Math.random()  +'px)}';
   css += '100% { transform: translate(0px)}';
   css += '}';
}
$( "<style>" + css + </style>").appendTo( "head" );
```

Finally you can assign each keyframe randomly to target divs:

```
$('.goldrocks-g').each(function(){
   (this).css({"animation": "shake" + Math.random()*10+1 +" 0.1s infinite");
})
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the easiest way to do this would be to have a random feeling shake animation that could be applied to all letters. Then you can randomly apply inline CSS of `animation-delay: 100ms` or `animation-delay: 300ms`. That style could be applied differently each time. All letters will be using the same shake animation but will be at different intervals in the animation based on their delay time.

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer as it suggests a new idea rather than the main problem asked on OP.

Comment: The solution literally reuses all of the OP's previous work and just randomly applies an animation delay to the respective divs. The solution you proposed throws all of that work out and randomly generates a ton of new CSS animations (all of which is going to be less performant). To be honest, it's kind of a dick move to downvote this answer just to get yours accepted.

Comment: The comment describes why I used vote down. I don't need those super virtual scores and the votes is the polite way to know if others agree with your answer or not! This is not a contest!

Comment: Nobody said it was a contest. The fact you feel the need to point that out is telling. Burying an answer that could prove helpful to others is my concern.